# How to deploy GTK# applications and supply dependencies. I get libgobject-2.0-0.dll exception

Tags: c#, gtk#

I have created a GTK# application which I intend to deploy on LINUX/Windows.

I would prefer not to require the target to install GTK or any other dependencies.

With this in mind, having developed the project, I instructed MonoDevelop to use 'local copy' of all its references.  This copies the associated DLLs to the build folder.

My questions:

1. Since setting dependencies to local I receive a runtime **System.TypeInitializationException** at **Gtk.Application.Init()**.  The complaint is below.  If I remove the 'local copy' setting for references I receive no runtime exception but I will not be able to deploy the application on a system which does not have GTK3# installed.  Any ideas?

> ***INNER EXCEPTION:***
>   System.DllNitFoundException: libgobject-2.0-0.dll.  ***MESSAGE:*** The type
>   initializer for 'GLib.GType' threw an exception.

2. Assuming I can resolve problem (1), is it possible to go further and package the dependencies into the built executable so that the exe does not rely on separated local copies of the dll files?

Many thanks in advance for any assistance provided to answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you not only need the C# DLL's for Gtk#, you also need the low-level DLL's for gtk+2 (the C library in which Gtk# is based on).

One strategy would be to deploy that DLL's with your program, but remember that you'll need a lot of them. The other one I can think of is to use the installer in mono-project.com, and launch it from the installer of your app.